# Reaching a specific word in a string

Tags: c++, string

Hi I have a string  like this:

> word1--tab--word2--tab--word3--tab--word4--tab--word5--tab--word6

I need to extract the third word from the string. I thought of reading character by character and getting the word after reading the second tab. But I guess it is inefficient. Can you show me a more specific way please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming "tab" is `\t`;

```
std::istringstream str(".....");
std::string temp, word;

str >> temp >> temp >> word;
```

Comment: yes tab is \t
But I couldn't make your code work..
Where should I write the string?
and what does std >> temp >> temp >> word; do?

Comment: @bahadirtr The string should go in the `istringstream` constructor argument list (where `"....."` is in the example code), and `std >> temp >> temp >> word;` has a typo, should be `str` instead of `std`. That extracts the first and second words into `temp` and the third word into `word`.

Comment: std::istringstream str(string)
this line gives this error :
variable 'std::istringstream str' has initializer but 
  incomplete type

Answer (score 5):

`std::string` has the `find` method which returns an index. You can use

```
 find("--", lastFoundIndex + 1)
```

three times to find the start index of your word, a fourth time for the end index, and then use `substr`.

Comment: this is definitely more efficient than my approach (and if "tab" is not `\t`)